# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text ** could not be parsed at index 20

Tags: java, datetime, datetimeformatter

Below is my code snippet and it is failing in my local but works in other DEV's machine, can someone give pointers on what am I missing?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a z");
ZonedDateTime releaseDate = ZonedDateTime
                .parse("2021-03-31 10:15:30 AM +05:30", formatter);
```

Exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-03-31 10:15:30 AM +05:30' could not be parsed at index 20

    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
```

Comment: Set up a Locale for the parser

Comment: Note that you probably don't want `HH` and `a` together.

Comment: (And include *the entire error message*, not just an extract of it.)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't _think_ a Locale should be required for this explicit format.

Comment: I have added the exception stacktrace

Comment: @chrylis Do all Locale use AM/PM? That's where the parser is failing

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hmm, I suppose it couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I note two problems with your pattern:

- You include `HH` (24-hour hour) and `a` (AM/PM). You probably want `hh`.
- You use `z` (time-zone **name**) but then show `+05:30`. Perhaps you want either `Z` or `X`.

Comment: I tried this formats and not helping 
"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a Z"


"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss X"

Comment: While both points denote real problems, none of them is the source of the exception. There are (at least) three problems with the code …

Comment: @OleV.V. any thoughts on what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Yes, @bharathsanjai, it’s a locale problem, Just as in the linked original question. You can find your answer there. If you read it and don’t understand it, or don’t understand how it applies to your situation, please revert, and we will guide you further.